# ndarray became str after writing into csv file. Now, can't read the values from csv

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas, multidimensional-array

I've created a csv file using 'Dictwriter'. two of the values in the 'dict' are NDarrays (3xn) where n is approximately 200. 
Now, I do pandas.read_csv the arrays are strings in the format "[[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]\r\n [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]\r..."

I checked the length of the string and got almost 900, but when trying to get the 10th element (for example) I get '.' instead of a value.

I've tried 'fromstring' but it failed.

Is there a way to go from this string back to ndarray?

Small piece of the csv:
[file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai3s6M1RzN7shVIgUeqHVlOHVttH)

Comment: Do you mind sharing the csv file? Or giving more info on how it looks like?
Are you trying to convert it to pandas dataframes or back to python dict?

Comment: I've added a link to a piece of the csv file.
I'm trying to convert it to pandas dataframe

Comment: Those `...,` bits in the array were added by you or by the Dictwriter? Looks like the csv file was not properly created and the data is incomplete.

Comment: Yep. I don't know why. I added it to the csv via:
writer.writerow({'ID': p, 'field1': array1, 'fileld2': array2})

The weirdest thing is that when i import the csv to dataframe, and check the length of one of the fields it returns very large number (the way it should be) but i can't get the full array